# Simple regular expression parsing in bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shell

I want to parse a log file (log.txt) which contains rows similar to these:

```
2010-10-19 07:56:14 URL:http://www.website.com/page.php?ID=26 [13676] -> "www.website.com/page.php?ID=26" [1]
2010-10-19 07:56:14 URL:http://www.website.com/page.php?ID=44 [14152] -> "www.website.com/page.php?ID=44" [1]
2010-10-19 07:56:14 URL:http://www.website.com/page.php?ID=13 [13681] -> "www.website.com/page.php?ID=13" [1]
2010-10-19 07:56:14 ERROR:Something bad happened
2010-10-19 07:56:14 ERROR:Something really bad happened
2010-10-19 07:56:15 URL:http://www.website.com/page.php?ID=14 [12627] -> "www.website.com/page.php?ID=14" [1]
2010-10-19 07:56:14 ERROR:Page not found
2010-10-19 07:56:15 URL:http://www.website.com/page.php?ID=29 [13694] -> "www.website.com/page.php?ID=29" [1]
```

As you might have guessed:

1) I need to extract this portion from each row:

```
2010-10-19 07:56:15 URL:http://www.website.com/page.php?ID=29 [13694] -> "www.website.com/page.php?ID=29" [1]
------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

2) This portion goes to another file (log.html) like this:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/page.php?ID=29">http://www.website.com/page.php?ID=29</a>
```

I need to do this via bash script, which will run on a *nix platform. I have no idea about shell programming so detailed script will be much appreciated, pointers to bash programming reference will do.

Comment: Bash doesn't do regexes. Use grep to find the matching lines, then awk to extract the relevant bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed -n 's%^.* URL:\(.*\) \[[0-9]*\] -> .*$%<a href="\1">\1</a>%p' log.txt
```

Comment: Do you *really* need the backslash before round brackets?

Comment: I had a terrible time with the backslashes and quotes but eventually got this to work:
sed -n "s@.\+ URL:\\([^ ]\+\\) .\+@\1@p" log.txt | sed "s@&@\&amp;@" > url.txt

Answer (score 5):

Here's a bash solution

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 4<"log.txt"
while read -r line<&4
do
  case "$line" in
    *URL:* )
      url="${line#*URL:}"
      url=${url%% [*}
      echo "<a href=\"${url}\">${url}</a>"
  esac
done
exec 4<&-
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small awk script that should do what you need.

```
awk '/URL:/ { sub(/^URL:/,"", $3); printf "<a href=\"%s"\">%s</a>\n", $3, $3; }'
```

Answer (score 1):

What about sed:

```
sed -n 's/.*URL:\([^ ]\+\) .*/<a href="\1">\1<\/a>/;/<a href/p' logfile
```

(Please note: you can address the URL part more properly, e.g. by the length of the date string in front of it, but I was just lazy.)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
while read line
do
        URL=$(echo $line | egrep -o 'URL:[^ ]+' | sed  's/^URL://')     
        if [ -n "$URL" ]; then
                echo "<a href=\"$URL\">$URL</a>" >> output.txt
        fi  
done < input.txt
```

Comment: using `egrep` to read the file is faster than the outer while loop. `egrep -o 'URL:[^ ]+' input.txt| sed .....|while read ....`. btw, `egrep` is `grep -E` now.

Comment: @ghostdog74: Thanks for the `egrep` tip. But didn't get the first part.

Comment: You have an outer while read loop that iterates the file, and for each line, you are calling 2 external commands, `egrep` and `sed` using pipes. This is expensive operation. Hence the suggestion to use `egrep` to iterate the file instead, since its optimized to go over files, large or small, more efficiently. And no, your script is not wrong, just not optimized in terms of speed, that's all. :)

Comment: I used part of this script to post-process the file.